# Dynamic Angular Interfaces With the Root Object Having Many Possible Numeric Options

Tags: angular, typescript, interface

I'm trying to map out an interface for my Angular project where a user can search a video game using the whattoplay api in RapidAPI. When you search the video game details, the result returns a game identified by it's numerical ID. That ID can be 25, or 105, or 3000, or many other possible numbers...

Interface I currently have...

```
export interface VideoGameDetails {
    gameID: {
        data: Game;
    }
}
```

All the results give me that object containing game data, but the gameID changes. I'm not sure how to make that root object dynamic and ready to use in other components who subscribe and receive such data.

***UPDATE***
In regards to using the below suggested interface, how would I go about accessing the data using a subscription to a method that returns such data.

Component that's subscribed to a method that fetches the data by the game id...

```
this.gameService.fetchSelectedGame(gameId)
      .subscribe((results) => {
        this.game = results;
      });
```

So based on that interface that I have to work with, an example of the results I'd receive is...

```
1468 {
   data: Game;
}
```

How would I dig down into the data object using that results parameter? I can't seem to use anything like results.id, or results.data. Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
export interface VideoGameDetails {
    [id: number]: {
        data: Game;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Warning: I did not compile or run or even syntax check this so... you've been warned :)
Usage example:

```
for (let k in results) {
    const result = results[k];
    console.log(result.data.someGameField);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. My text editor seems to have no problem with that interface, but I'm just having trouble digging down into the received data when the id is a changing number. I've updated the above question to elaborate on it further.

Comment: I updated my answer with a usage example, please take a look.

Comment: That worked beautifully. Thank you so much!

Comment: It does give me an undefined at the end of the loop, but I just simply applied a break; after that first iteration.